# VLOOKUP not giving expected results

Tags: excel, vlookup

I've used `VLOOKUP` plenty of times, but this has really stumped me. I have a VBA code that copies data from one workbook to another and then I'm trying to perform the `VLOOKUP` on the data that I've copied.

Here's an example of how the data I've copied is layed out in Sheet2:

5009 | Materials | Store Items

The table that has been copied is given the name "AutoList" for the range of the table (Theres a lot more than this obviously)

The table I'm trying to use the `VLOOKUP` on looks like this:

[`VLOOKUP`] | Materials | Z | X | C | V

The formula I am using is:

`=VLOOKUP("Materials",AutoList,1,0)`

I can't for the life of me figure out why I am getting #N/A as the result. If I remove the 0 on the end (for the logic), I end up with the last number in the AutoList table for every result as it's only doing a partial match.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: look at the following 
`Syntax
VLOOKUP has the following syntax:
VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,[range_lookup])`
[VLookup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797422(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: That's what I've done...  `lookup_value` = "materials", `table_array` = AutoList, `col_index` = 1, [`range_lookup`] =0

Comment: If you use `=` to see if `materials` is actually equal to `materials` what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the "lookup_value" in the first column of your "table_array"...?

Comment: ... No... I realise my mistake haha. Might have to switch the columns around to get this to work!

Comment: You can use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` if you want to avoid switching the order of columns. There are numerous examples of such technique on the Internet.

Comment: this mistake is very common

Answer (score 1):

According to Excel's help file vlookup looks, "for a value in the leftmost column of a table." Does AutoList define your range with "Materials" in the first column? If so, then shouldn't the result of your vlookup formula return "Materials"?

Comment: I did try this, making it so materials was the first column (starting AutoList range in column B), but the info I need is in column A, so when I select 1 as the col_index, I just get materials again because that's the first column of the table_array